# Facebook Ads Indexing

Tags: java, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-conversions-api

I have an android game, where i want to initialize Facebook SDK to track installs. However, I do not understand, what information will be recorded by Facebook and how would i identify the install in Facebook. Is it advertizer_id? How can i access this advertizer_id inside the app then? Will i be able to send info to facebook using conversions api, referring to this advertizer_id or i need another id for that? Thank you!

I have tried to init Facebook SDK inside app and the only info i received is that the app was installed in my developer account.